# F# thinks my type is not defined

Tags: c#, f#

I am starting to play around with F# so I thought I would start by using it for unit testing. The problem is that Visual Studio keeps telling me that the type is not defined for some of the types I am using and I can't understand why.

I have imported the namespace and the type that I am using is public. Here is the F# code:

```
namespace OpcPersistenceTest

open System
open NUnit.Framework
open OpcPersistence
open OpcPersistence.Data

[<TestFixture>]
type PushServicesTesting() =

    [<Test>]
    let ``create a subscription, then shutdown service, start service, should retrieve original subscription`` =
        let filters = new ResizeArray<Filter>()
        [new Filter(Operand = "EventType", Operator = "=", Value = "SimpleAlarm");
         new Filter(Operand = "Area", Operator = "=", Value = "Area_A")] 
         |> Seq.iter filters.Add

        let keys = new ResizeArray<string>()
        [Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); Guid.NewGuid().ToString();] |> Seq.iter keys.Add

        let configId = PushServices.CreateSubscription(filters, keys)
        PushServices.Shutdown()
        PushServices.Startup()
        let subscription = PushServices.GetSubscriptions(configId)
```

And some of the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace OpcPersistence.Data
{
    public struct Filter
    {
        public string Operand { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
        ...
```

The type *Filter* is apparently undefined (so is the type *PushServices*) but if I swap it out for another class in the same namespace, I do not have this problem. I have even tried changing the name of the class but to no avail. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

It also doesn't show up in intellisense as the rest of the namespace does as depicted in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Do you know what [type inferencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) is?

Comment: Yes, I know what type inferencing is.

Comment: Can you come up with a minimal code that we could try out and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Have you built since you added the reference?

Comment: Yes, I have but I have also been doing a lot of refactoring since and the code can't compile right now. I will try to get it in a state that it can build as soon as possible and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @JohnPalmer I did what I needed to do to make the solution build. F# is now able to identify my type. Thank you for the simple suggestion. I could of sworn I did this already but I guess not. You could put that up as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this apparently solved the problem (from the comments)

When you are using multiple projects, the intellisense and error messages may not be correct, particularly if you change a file in another project without building.

Rebuilding the solution can make the problem go away.